# Help me assess my internet connection's problem

Tags: network, wifi, internet

I'm currently pinging `google.com` to find a trend and pinpoint the problem. The internet keeps disconnecting every few mins and I have no idea why.

What I realised is that between every 4-6 pings I get one `request timeout`, and sometimes the latency goes up to `time=100` and above or `time=1000` and above, in which the internet's speed becomes really slow. Sometimes I get 4 or more timeouts in one succession. I also observed that the latency is low and steady (with minor fluctuations) if I'm not browsing anything, as soon as I hit refresh or load a page the whole thing goes into a spiral of timeouts and very high latency.

However, restarting my connection by toggling WiFi on and off quickly resets the connection and I get good latency, that until the whole process repeats.

Anyone knows what may be the problem ? I am at a serviced apartment with Wifi shared on multiple channels. Also, I have a Retina without the Ethernet adapter, so I cannot check that right now.

*edit* It's 4AM in the morning and I have no timeouts and pretty quick latency, I'm sure this finding has some value.

Comment: On shared wifi there are so many variables it's hard to even begin to figure this out.  The problem being you have no valid info on other users and their settings.  Anohter thing you don't know about the other users is what malware they have picked up.

Comment: I understand that point, but it seems I might be the only one with the problem because I wasn't told anyone else is complaining. I am currently staying in the last room adjacent to another hotel, could their WiFi be interfering in my room causing all these problems ? *edit* It's early in the morning and there are no problems currently, maybe it's because everyone is sleeping and there's minimum interference ?